# Motion on fractal media

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fractals

Can physical quantities such as displacement and velocity be defined for a body moving in fractional dimensions?

For a point particle, the distance/displacement between any two points would be infinite for an ideal fractal. The situation would be a bit different if we consider real world examples, say in biology, the self-similarity would stop at some scale. How do we still use concepts from fractional calculus to define such quantities (if at all)?

References supporting the answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Moving in fractional dimensions" doesn't match what you describe. The idealised fractal is an infinitely sized surface of m dimensions embedded in a finite region of n (>m) domensional space. "Motion" is defined on either the m or n dimensional spaces.

Comment: Actually, consider a fractal set $F$ embedded in some suitable D-dimensional space. We can look at a function $x: t\rightarrow f\in F$ as a motion of a point in the fractal. While the velocity  $x'(t)$ in the embedding space might be badly defined, it is not obvious to me that fractional derivatives have to diverge.